# Mysql запрос к 2-м таблицам и вывод ВСЕХ найденных в поле URL названий фото

Tags: php, mysql

Ситуация непонятная с запросом `Mysql`.

Есть 2 таблицы `rent` и `rent_photo`

1. `rent` содержит (`id`) поле.
2. `rent_photo` (`id`, `rent_id`, `photo`).

Сопоставляю 2 таблицы в запросе, чтобы все `rent.id` которые совпали с `rent_photo ( поле id)` выводил `photo`. Если быть точнее там хранятся названия фотографий, которые вывожу в

```
<img src="">
```

Проблем заключается в том, что таблице rent_photo содержится к примеру 5-10 фотографий на каждое id, а выводится только 1.

Запрос к БД использую Redbean php

```
$ads = R::getAssoc('SELECT
            rent.id, 
            rent.town_sell,
            rent_photo.photo AS img,
  LEFT JOIN rent_photo ON rent.id = rent_photo.rent_id
     WHERE rent.id= '.$id.' ');
```

`print_r($ads)` выводит весь массив данных, данные верны, но фото из поля `img` выводится только 1, когда их там 5-10 штук.

Данные из запроса вывожу так.

```
<?php if(isset($A['img'])): ?>
              
            <img src="../../Download_Rent/<?=$A['img'] ?>" >
               
             
  <?php else: ?>
        <img src="../../Photo/No photo.jpg" >
                         <?php endif; ?>
```

Пробовал так, тоже ничего.

```
<?php if(isset($A['id']['img'])): ?>
  <?php foreach ($A['id']['img'] as $img): { 
                      
        echo'    <img src="../../Download_Rent/<?=$img ?>" '>
                    }
             
                   <?php endforeach; ?>

               
             
  <?php else: ?>
        <img src="../../Photo/No photo.jpg">
                         <?php endif; ?>
```

В чем проблема? В запросе к базе Mysql или же в цикле PHP? Помогите пожалуйста с ответом.

Comment: Если в ответе Вы получаете все данные, то проблема в цикле. Скорее всего проблема просто в том, что данные Вам необходимо выводить через foreach($ads as $item) { echo '<img src="../../Download_Rent/<?=$item['img'] ?>" ';}

Comment: @Denis640Kb  так вообще выдает ошибку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если нужны только фото, то может лучше, сразу обратится к таблице rent_photo?!

```
$ads = R::getAssoc('SELECT `photo` AS img FROM `rent_photo` WHERE `rent_id`= '.$id);
```

По выводу, попробуйте так:

```
<?php if(!empty($A)) : ?>
    <?php foreach ($A as $img) : ?>
        <img src="../../Download_Rent/<?=$img ?>" '>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

* $A - должна быть массивом с изображениями

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, практически подобрались к ответу с вами. Выводит вот такой массив, почему-то дублирует команды. Array ( [3624_5f0ce68b061f3.jpg] => 3624_5f0ce68b061f3.jpg [3624_5f0ce68b073d0.jpg] => 3624_5f0ce68b073d0.jpg )   Пока вопрос не решен((

Comment: Все получилось!!! Немного поколдовал с вашим примером и теперь все отображается))) Спасибо огромное!!!! Здоровья и успехов вам!!!